# SQL Server Case statement for date condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table which keeps `ProductCode`, `Start_Date`, `End_date` and prices for different products. I want create a view from this table and create a conditional column 'Status' and I need to assign the status of Product on the basis of how old it is and I want to keep that status same on every row.
How can I write a 'case' statement to create column 'Status'?

If ProductCode started in 2019 - 'Old', if it started in 2020 - 'Mature', if it is started in 2021 - 'New'.

[image: Desired view]

Comment: I would use a conditional join to the date to show the aging category

Comment: Could you right something for me please? I tried to write a case statement but it is not giving me the correct result...

Comment: you need to join to a subquery of same table with min(StartDate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you need a combination of `CASE` expression and windowed `MIN()`:

```
SELECT 
   *,
   CASE 
      WHEN MIN(Start_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Product_Code) = 2019 THEN 'Old'
      WHEN MIN(Start_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Product_Code) = 2020 THEN 'Mature'
      WHEN MIN(Start_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Product_Code) = 2021 THEN 'New'
      ELSE ''
   END AS Status
FROM (VALUES
   ('abc10', 2019, 2020, 10),
   ('abc10', 2020, 2021, 11),
   ('abc10', 2021, 2025, 12),
   ('abc11', 2020, 2021, 10),
   ('abc11', 2021, 2025, 12),
   ('abc12', 2021, 2025, 15)
) t (Product_Code, Start_Date, End_Date, Price)
ORDER BY Product_Code, Start_Date
```

Result:

| Product_Code | Start_Date | End_Date | Price | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc10 | 2019 | 2020 | 10 | Old |
| abc10 | 2020 | 2021 | 11 | Old |
| abc10 | 2021 | 2025 | 12 | Old |
| abc11 | 2020 | 2021 | 10 | Mature |
| abc11 | 2021 | 2025 | 12 | Mature |
| abc12 | 2021 | 2025 | 15 | New |

Comment: A bit out of context question but how do you design these codes and get the result at the same page for testing? Is there a tool or website or just SSMS ?

Comment: @Andy, I use dbfiddle.uk sometimes. And SSMS of course.

Comment: @Andy - There's also a few other sites like http://sqlfiddle.com. I use both it and dbfiddle.uk. One nice feature sqlfiddle.com has is a "Text to DDL" option which let's you paste a delimited table of data, like the one above, and auto generates the DDL's.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Updated for join.

```
SELECT 
    t.productcode
    ,Start_Date
    ,End_Date
    ,Price
    ,s.Status
FROM t1 as t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        productcode
        ,CASE 
            WHEN MIN(Start_Date) = 2019 THEN 'Old'
            WHEN MIN(Start_Date) = 2020 THEN 'Mature' 
            WHEN MIN(Start_Date) = 2021 THEN 'New'
            ELSE 'Unknown'
        END AS Status
    FROM t1
    group by productcode
) as s on t.productcode = s.productcode
```

Generally speaking, you wouldn't want to hardcode these values but rather use some logic to determine Old, mature and new. As time progresses, 2021 will turn into Mature, then Old, so on and so forth. Someone will need to remember to maintain this and update the years. It would be more advisable to use `DATEDIFF` based on either the maximum date in the data or the current date using `GETDATE()` depending on your requirements.

Comment: I think this will not give correct status for all the rows. If I use this case statement, abc10 will be 'Old' in first row, 'Mature' in second row and 'New' in third row. I am expecting it to be 'Old' every time because it started in 2019 irrespective of the price change every year..I hope I am clear

Comment: I see. Let me update my answer.